# ¿como crear un hilo en c++ con windows usando _beginthreadex?

Tags: c++, windows, hilos

Estoy intentando crear un hilo dentro de una función miembro de una clase con _beginthreadex.

```
void CapturaDeRed::startCapture() {
    unsigned threadID;
    HANDLE hTread;
     MyData *data=NULL;
    data->ifaceName = configCapture();
    data->s1 = configSniffer();
    //creo el hil y lo asigno
    hTread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CapturarPacket1, data, 0, &threadID);
}
```

Pero el compilador me arroja el siguiente error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)      argument of type "unsigned int (__stdcall CapturaDeRed::*)(void *ap)" is incompatible with parameter of type "_beginthreadex_proc_type"

Pongo todo el código de la implementación:

```
#include "..\Include\CapturaDeRed.h"

using namespace Tins;

CapturaDeRed::CapturaDeRed() 
{

};

CapturaDeRed::~CapturaDeRed()
{
}

unsigned  __stdcall CapturaDeRed::CapturarPacket1( void *ap ) 
{
    dta =  (MyData*)ap;
    Sniffer snfi(dta->ifaceName.name(), dta->s1);
    Packet pack(snfi.next_packet());
    do {
        const TCP & tcp = pack.pdu()->rfind_pdu<TCP>();
        TCP tcp1 = TCP(tcp);
    } while (true);
    _endthreadex(0);
    //return 0;
}

void CapturaDeRed::clasificarPacket() {
}

const NetworkInterface CapturaDeRed::configCapture() {
    NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface::default_interface();
    return iface;
}

const SnifferConfiguration CapturaDeRed::configSniffer() {
    SnifferConfiguration sc;
    sc.set_promisc_mode(true);
    sc.set_snap_len(64 *1024);
    sc.set_filter("ip and tcp");
    return sc;
}

void CapturaDeRed::startCapture() {
    unsigned threadID;
    HANDLE hTread;
    MyData *data=NULL;
    data->ifaceName = configCapture();
    data->s1 = configSniffer();
    //creo el hil y lo asigno
    hTread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CapturarPacket1, data, 0, &threadID);
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Comment: ¿Te funciona algo? Creas un puntero de `MyData` a `NULL` y lo primero que haces con ello es acceder a un miembro: `data->ifaceName`, `data->s1`: Eso te dará un fallo en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Gracias @PaperBirdMaster, tienes todo la razón, no había podido contestar, sin embargo ya realice la corrección del código  lo e dejado de esta forma `MyData *data=new MyData`, eliminando `data` después de su implementación. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por aquí la norma es que el código que pongas debe ser mínimo y que compile, que no es el caso. De todos modos, algo que debes tener en cuenta es que un puntero a función no es el mismo tipo de bestia que un puntero a función miembro no estática, de ahí el mensaje de error

> "unsigned int (__stdcall CapturaDeRed::*)(void *ap)" is incompatible
>   with parameter of type "_beginthreadex_proc_type"

Así que una de dos, o declaras a CapturarPacket1() como estática

> static unsigned __stdcall CapturarPacket1(void* ap);

o la hacer una función normal.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho. e cambiado el método por una función dentro de mi .cpp (a un con dudas). Gracias